# How to install nodejs in linux vm if wget is not working

Tags: linux, wget, node.js

I want to install `nodejs` in `Linux` from command prompt. I am using

`wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v15.6.0/node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz`

but getting error

```
--2021-01-15 16:15:42--  http://nodejs.org/dist/v15.6.0/node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving nodejs.org (nodejs.org)... 134.60.42.42, 124.90.21.16, 6606:4760:10::1214:163e, ...
Connecting to nodejs.org (nodejs.org)|134.60.42.42|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to nodejs.org (nodejs.org)|134.60.42.42|:80...
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Try to add verbose mode and also increase timeout, also it's possible that you are behind a proxy and you are not allowed to access internet.

Comment: @RedaSalih - Yeah I am behind the proxy but I have updated proxy settings. Is there alternate way to install node.

Comment: Try using a package manager as suggested in the below answer using node js official repositories

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of options to download node binary and install from there:

As **GAD3R** suggest you can use curl,

Or you can also install via package manager, in this link information for different Linux distributions: [NodeJS Package Manager Installation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

Please also refer to this section for more info [NodeJS Download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

E.g: `apt install nodejs`

Comment: It's not about only downloading, I want to install in VM via commnad prompt.

Comment: package-manager will handle the download and install for you? If you are in Linux-debian distro could you try `apt install nodejs` You could also check If you can install `nvm`

Comment: It is saying apt: invalid flag install for both nodejs and nvm.

Comment: Try this, taken from another answer: `sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f`` https://askubuntu.com/a/141374  Then. try to do installation again

Comment: `apt-get` not working. I tried with `yum`, first one worked, for second it said `no such option -f`.

Comment: `yum install nodejs` saying `you should be root user` and `sudo yum install nodejs` saying `no package available error nothing to do`

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905824/6668216

Comment: All the queries are saying `no package found nothing to do`

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl`:

```
curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.6.0/node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz --output nodejs.tar.gz
```

Comment: I'm not sure how is this going to help?

Comment: I tried this but getting error ` --:--:--  0:03:33 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2606:4700:10::6824:272e: Network is unreachable` Is there other way to install node.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya: the are problems with your network settings, all tools will fail.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I am using VDI not local machine. In VDI browser I can access sites only which is allowed not like news wallpaper or node.org etc. In the same VDI I have VM. I needed to do few changes related to proxy, I did. Now I am expecting I should be able to install nodejs. Many things getting failed which is related to downloading something. I am using Putty.

Comment: Can I fix this adding `134.60.42.42|:80` in proxy or something