# How can I install nodejs manually in Linux from terminal

Tags: linux, node.js

I have downloaded `Nodejs` in my `Linux VM` from nodejs.org, I want to install it from terminal. VM have `node v0.12.18` manually installed by someone else, I don't know how to do that. As I am installing `nodejs` offline, I should not depend on that whether or not `npm` installed.

I have tried `npm install node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Getting below error

```
sudo npm install node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm WARN excluding symbolic link bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.                                                                                        js
npm WARN excluding symbolic link bin/npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.                                                                                        js
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/usermachinename/node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.g                                                                                        z
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v0.12.18-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/loc                                                                                        al/lib/nodejs/node-v0.12.18-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install" "node-v15.6.0-linux-x64                                                                                        .tar.gz"
npm ERR! node v0.12.18
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! path /tmp/npm-1637-a9cb4311/unpack-5a7f411732fb/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/tmp/npm-1637-a9cb4311/unpack-5a7f411732fb/package                                                                                        .json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/usermachinename/npm-debug.log
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you say that "_this is not working_" what happens? What didn't happen? Did you get any errors - what were they? From where did you download `nodejsfilename.tar.gz`? Is `npm` even installed?

Comment: Is this question materially different to your earlier related questions [tar.unpack untar error while installing angular in Linux vm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/629653/100397) or even [How to install nodejs in linux vm if wget is not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/629335/100397)?

Comment: @roaima - This is different/new question. Please check my updated question. Apologies for not posting all the information. I have downloaded this file from nodejs.org

Comment: [How to install Node.js via binary archive on Linux](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux) (linked from [nodejs.org/en/download/current/](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)).

Comment: @Freddy - Thank you. I can only see steps there for unzip not for installation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using your distribution's [own packaged version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)?

Comment: @roaima - I am new to Linux, not sure what you are saying. In my VM internet is not working due to proxy restrictions. That's why planning to install node manually.

Comment: Don't try to work around the proxy restrictions - that'll only come back and hurt you later. Get them fixed properly (and officially, if working on company purposes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to install NodeJS you need to follow the installation instructions

This is wrong:

> ```
> npm install node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
> ```

The best option may be simply to use the version [packaged for your Linux distribution](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).

However, if you really want to do it yourself, the [download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) has [installation instructions](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux), which explains that for a tar archive such as this you simply unpack it into the target directory.

For example,

```
VERSION=v15.6.0
DISTRO=linux-x64
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs
sudo tar -xJvf node-$VERSION-$DISTRO.tar.xz -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

Then set the environment variables and add this to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Nodejs
VERSION=v15.6.0
DISTRO=linux-x64
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I am getting this error `tar xf node-v15.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz  /usr/local/lib/   tar: /usr/local/lib: Not found in archive tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Comment: That's because you're not following the instructions correctly